# Have philosophers debated the notion that "existence or the capacity for experience" may be homo sapiens' fundamental value?

Tags: ethics

I assume the 2600-year search for an ethical principle has two challenges: establishing homo sapiens' fundamental value; and articulating principles of action that target that value. Have philosophers debated the notion that existence or the capacity for experience may be homo sapiens' fundamental value?

Comment: I think they are about to.

Comment: @ScottRowe ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha! Many thanks for cheering me. (Where you impressed that I had the will power to restrain from adding the clichéd 'up'?)

Comment: I think the fundamental value has been pretty well known, with the ideas of self-actualization and 'Arete'. People seem to want to debate it, but they just need to make an obviously better proposal and everyone will assent to it. In Nonduality, the idea of value goes away, so the debates and problems largely do as well. It is the objective result of self-development.

Comment: Isn't that basically the fundamental principle of existentialism?

Comment: Why assume that the phrase “*Homo sapiens*’ fundamental value” has a well-defined referent? That it is a syntactically valid noun phrase doesn’t guarantee that it has a meaning.